# How does linq Any() works internally

Tags: c#, linq

I'm intrigued to know how someCollection.Any() internally works.
how can I see this code ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383749/How-does-it-work-in-Csharp-Part-3-Csharp-LINQ-in-d#paraIdAny

Comment: And you can always get the full source code for .net: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the LINQ methods are actually extension methods of `IEnumerable`.

Here is what Reflector decompiles the `Any` LINQ method to:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        if (predicate(local))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would be perplexed if it did anything else.

Comment: @anthony-arnold take a look at Math.Abs() then and you will :D