# How many times select's method is run when using Select(...).Any(...)?

Tags: c#, linq

First, I have this code, it will break the 2nd loop if the condition is met.

So for example, if at first time, the condition is met, other elements of the 2nd loop will not be enumerated.

```
foreach (var evaluator in strategyEvaluators)
{
   foreach (var rule in concatedRules)
   {
        var isEntryRuleMet = evaluator.Evaluate(rule.Code);

        if (isEntryRuleMet)
        {
           matchedNames.Add(evaluator.Name);
           break;
        }
   }
}
```

But I also find out that the code can be shorten in this way:

```
foreach (var evaluator in strategyEvaluators)
{
   if (concatedRules.Select(rule=> evaluator.Evaluate(rule.Code)).Any(isEntryRuleMet => isEntryRuleMet))
   {
       matchedNames.Add(evaluator.Name);
   }
}
```

Notice that for the 2nd way, I don't know how many times the `Select` method will be run.

**Is `Select` stopped right after `Any` returns true? Or is it finished running and then `Any` is run?**

Comment: Yes, this is called "lazy evaluation", and the LINQ-to-Objects extension methods try hard to use lazy evaluation whenever possible.  A few that don't (because they can't) are `ToList`, `ToArray`, and `OrderBy`.

Comment: concatedRules.Where(rule=> evaluator.Evaluate(rule.Code)).Any() would be more accurate

Comment: When I do this: concatedRules.Where(rule=> evaluator.Evaluate(rule.Code)).Any(),

VS hints me to do this instead: concatedRules.Any(rule => strategyAlert.Evaluate(rule.Code))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is Select stopped right after Any returns true? Or is it finished running and then Any is run?

Yes, it is. You can think it like this way: `Select` yields elements to `Any` as long as it returns `false`, once it returns `true`, it stops.Remaining elements are not yielded.

Here is a simple program that demonsrates it:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var query = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x => GetNumber(x)).Any(x => x > 5);       
}


public static int GetNumber(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetNumber is called: {0}", x);
    return x;
}

// Output:

GetNumber is called: 0
GetNumber is called: 1
GetNumber is called: 2
GetNumber is called: 3
GetNumber is called: 4
GetNumber is called: 5
GetNumber is called: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

`Select` will stop running after the `Any` is met. So as soon as [Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393766/how-does-linq-any-works-internally) returns true it breaks out of the foreach loop and doesn't materialize the collection anymore.

you may even want to write the code as

```
foreach (var evaluator in strategyEvaluators)
{
   if (concatedRules.Any(rule=>evaluator.Evaluate(rule.Code)))
   {
       matchedNames.Add(evaluator.Name);
   }
}
```

this way you don't even have to worry about the select at all.

Comment: Thanks and this is the correct link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393766/how-does-linq-any-works-internally

Answer (score 1):

Iteration stops when the first `Any` is successful.

You can even make your code smaller by doing this:

```
var matchedNames =
    strategyEvaluators
        .Where(evaluator =>
            concatedRules
                .Where(rule => evaluator.Evaluate(rule.Code))
                .Any())
        .Select(evaluator => evaluator.Name)
        .ToList();
```

And if `matchedNames` is already defined then try this:

```
matchedNames
    .AddRange(
        strategyEvaluators
            .Where(evaluator =>
                concatedRules
                    .Where(rule => evaluator.Evaluate(rule.Code))
                    .Any())
            .Select(evaluator => evaluator.Name));
```