# C# Linq ANY vs ALL - Performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am trying to figure out how does ANY and ALL work in Linq.

Lets say I have 100k records in a list. Which one should perform faster?

```
if(recordsList.All(r => r.Deleted)) { }
```

or

```
if(!recordsList.Any(r => !r.Deleted)) { }
```

I would think that ANY should perform faster in case the first record on the list is deleted it should stop and return true, instead of using ALL which will always check whole list... right?

Comment: @HimBromBeere tried but for both I am getting <1ms :/

Comment: They will both stop on the first item that does/doesn't match (`.All` will stop on the first item that does not match, `.Any` will stop on the first item that does match)

Comment: shouldn't be the second one just `Any(r => !r.Deleted)`?

Comment: then why do you bother about 1ms for 100000 items? If the difference is that low I'd say you can completely ignore it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere of course, every `== true` could be removed, and every `== false` could be replaced with a `!`

Comment: @Rafalon are you sure about that? Is there some source on how exactly it works?

Comment: @Rafalon That was'nt my point, I also deleted the second false-check, not just the first one.

Comment: @HimBromBeere because the function that does it for less than 1ms is called in a loop that is called 1m times that comes from another loop that is called 10m times, then if it is 0.00030 ms * 100m times

Comment: If you really carse for the difference you probably should create a better benchmark-test, e.g. with 10mio items. No-one here can better answer this question than you.

Comment: .NET is open source. See [Any](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1296) and [All](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1305) implementations.

Comment: "***The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined***" - from [this documentation of `All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0) and [this documentation of `Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @vernou so it is exactly same. Thank you!

Comment: This is the answer to your problems https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about measuing time-difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See how `Any` [works internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393766/how-does-linq-any-works-internally):

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        if (predicate(local))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So it stops once found a predicate that is evaluated to true.

In the same manner `All` stops once a predicate that is evaluated to false:

```
public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    foreach (TSource current in source)
    {
        if (!predicate(current))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So I think the answer here is that both options should have similar to no difference.

Comment: I would probably suggest saying that the difference between the two methods is very deterministic based on your data.   Choosing should ultimately depend on what property your testing and finding the one that has the greater chance to [Short-Circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) First.  And that's it possible to setup the logic such that they would perform exactly the same for the same set of data.